# How much heat is needed for an atom to be ionized?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, plasma-physics, ions, ionization-energy

We all know that heat or high voltage makes atoms into an excited state, stripping off the electrons off of their nucleus. But how much heat do you exactly need to create plasma, or have the majority of the atoms to be ionized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elements and their plasma state](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/346027/)

Comment: It depends on the ionization energy of the atom.  See the answers to this similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132204/.  As electrons are stripped off, the ionization energy increases for electrons closer to the nucleus.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to physics. Can you explain what a nucleus is, and how it's related to ionization energy? Thanks!

Comment: The nucleus is the positively charged center of the atom (the thing that attracts the electrons). The closer you are to the nucleus, the stronger the attraction and the harder it is to extract the electron. As a rule of thumb, kinetic energy of a molecule at room temperature (293 K) is about 1/40th eV. Ionization energy is usually expressed in eV. But because not all collisions have the same energy, you will get considerable ionization before the average kinetic energy reaches the ionization energy.

Comment: I have another question.  Since there is a lot of solar wind in the north and south poles, Is it possible for us to use it as energy?

Answer (score 1):

Take the table on Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy) as a source for the ionisation energies for various atoms.

Ionisation Energies in $kj/mol$
$$
\begin{array} 
 s   & 1st  & 2nd & 3rd & 4th & 5th & 6th & 7th & \\ 
 Na & 496 & 4560 &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
 Mg & 738 & 1450 & 7730 &  &  &  &  \\ 
 Al & 577 & 1816 & 2881 & 11600 &  &  &  \\ 
 Si & 786 & 1577 & 3228 & 4354 & 16100 &  &  \\ 
 P & 1060 & 1890 & 2905 & 4950 & 6270 & 21200 &  \\ 
 S & 999.6 & 2260 & 3375 & 4565 & 6950 & 8490 & 27107 \\ 
 Cl & 1256 & 2295 & 3850 & 5160 & 6560 & 9360 & 11000 \\ 
 Ar & 1520 & 2665 & 3945 & 5770 & 7230 & 8780 & 12000
\end{array}
$$

Using $1\space eV\approx96.48\space kj/mol$ one can convert it to

Ionisation Energies in $eV$
$$
\begin{array}
    s   & 1st  & 2nd & 3rd & 4th & 5th & 6th & 7th & \  \\ 
 Na & 5.14 & 47.26 & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ 
 Mg & 7.65 & 15.03 & 80.12 & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ 
 Al & 5.98 & 18.82 & 29.86 & 120.23 & \  & \  & \  \\ 
 Si & 8.15 & 16.34 & 33.46 & 45.13 & 166.87 & \  & \  \\ 
 P & 10.99 & 19.59 & 30.11 & 51.3 & 64.98 & 219.72 & \  \\ 
 S & 10.36 & 23.42 & 34.9 & 47.31 & 72.03 & 87.99 & 280.95 \\ 
 Cl & 13.02 & 23.79 & 39.9 & 53.48 & 67.99 & 97.01 & 114.01 \\ 
 Ar & 15.75 & 27.62 & 40.89 & 59.8 & 74.93 & 91 & 124.37
\end{array}
$$

By using $1\space eV\approx11604\space K$ one convert it to

Ionisation Temperatures in $K$
$$
\begin{array}
    s& 1st  & 2nd & 3rd & 4th & 5th & 6th & 7th & \  \\ 
 Na & 59653 & 548419 & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ 
 Mg & 88757 & 174388 & 929667 & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ 
 Al & 69394 & 218406 & 346490 & 1395102 & \  & \  & \  \\ 
 Si & 94530 & 189662 & 388223 & 523644 & 1936305 & \  & \  \\ 
 P & 127483 & 227305 & 349377 & 595324 & 754077 & 2549669 & \  \\ 
 S & 120219 & 271804 & 405902 & 549021 & 835858 & 1021070 & 3260088 \\ 
 Cl & 151056 & 276014 & 463029 & 620580 & 788954 & 1125703 & 1322941 \\ 
 Ar & 182806 & 320513 & 474455 & 693943 & 869533 & 1055948 & 1443209 
\end{array}
$$

So, if you, for example, heat a $Na$ atom to $59653\space K$ then you would have a $Na^+$ ion and heat it further to $548419\space K$ then you would have a $Na^{2+}$ ion and so on.